# 2 different audio devices recognized as one

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard, sound-card

A few days ago I bought myself a new motherboard/CPU and rebuilt my PC.
Before that, I had 2 audio devices plugged in. One in the back and one in the front and Windows 10 correctly identified both of them and gave them seperate names. Using the `Sound` Menu, I could swap between them.

My new Motherboard is the `Gigabyte Aorus Extreme`. I plugged both my speakers into my pc. Again one in the front and one in the back. Now what happens is this:

- If I have both of them plugged in, I can only see the device which is plugged in in the front and only that one plays a sound
- If I unplug the one in the front, I still only see the device in the front but the one in the back is playing the sound
- If I unplug both of them, no sound is played.

So it seems like both devices are identified as the same object and the sound from the one in the front is taken if available.

I don't know how I could fix this. Is this a software or hardware problem?

I am very happy for any advice/help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which type of Gigabyte Aorus Xtreme do you have? They should all use Realtek as their audio drivers. I would search up your specific model and download the Realtek HD Audio Driver from the download section on their Gigabyte web page. This will add the Realtek program to your PC as well where you can change the way your motherboard sees audio devices. There is an option in there to separate or combine the front and back audio panels on your PC.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Thought windows would install them itself but guess it didnt.